# android-removing child from parent & freeing memory

Tags: android, parent-child

I need to show an image in beginning of my app and then hide and remove it from it's parent:

```
(image.getParent()).removeView(image);
```

will removing it from its parent free memory, too?

Comment: if you post your chunk of code, would be more easy to answer ..

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ImageView, then you can try calling recycle() method .

Comment: in `onDestroy` method of my second activity, I call what you said. but when later I want to start the activity again it gives me error. why?

Comment: can you post your logcat errors,so that I can get better insight ?

Comment: interesting! I'm not getting any error now! but previous times it said `trying to use a recycled Bitmap`, sth like that